# D3 click event redirect to Angular route

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I am using D3 and I am trying to add a clicked event to the path elements which would redirect to an Angular event.

```
<svg>
   <path class="state" d="M144.69443,382.19813L148.63451,381.70951L150.12055,379.69807L150.66509,376.75698L147.11357,376.16686L146.5994,375.49864L147.0769,373.46633L146.91762,372.87666L148.84019,372.25707L151.88297,369.42439L152.46453,364.42929L153.84443,361.02718L155.78772,358.86092L159.30659,357.27125L160.96098,355.66642L161.02971,353.55758L160.03638,352.97757L159.01323,351.90484L157.85801,346.05639L155.17281,341.2263L155.73862,337.7213L153.31904,336.69199L84.257718,232.51359L103.15983,164.9121L36.079967,149.21414L34.573071,153.94738L34.41141,161.38376L29.238275,173.18497L26.166727,175.77154L25.843406,176.90316L24.06514,177.71147L22.610196,181.91464L21.801894,185.14785L24.550122,189.35102L26.166727,193.55419L27.29835,197.11072L26.975029,203.57714L25.196764,206.64869L24.550122,212.46847L23.580159,216.18666L25.358424,220.06651L28.106652,224.593L30.369899,229.44282L31.663182,233.48433L31.339862,236.71754L31.016541,237.20252L31.016541,239.3041L36.674657,245.60886L36.189676,248.03377L35.543034,250.29702L34.896392,252.23694L35.058052,260.48163L37.159638,264.19982L39.099564,266.78638L41.847792,267.27137L42.817755,270.01959L41.686132,273.57612L39.584545,275.19273L38.452922,275.19273L37.64462,279.07258L38.129601,281.98247L41.362811,286.3473L42.979415,291.6821L44.434359,296.37025L45.727643,299.4418L49.122513,305.26158L50.577457,307.84814L51.062439,310.75803L52.679043,311.72799L52.679043,314.1529L51.870741,316.09283L50.092476,323.20589L49.607494,325.14581L52.032402,327.89404L56.235574,328.37902L60.762067,330.15729L64.641918,332.25887L67.551807,332.25887L70.461695,335.33042L73.048262,340.18024L74.179886,342.44348L78.059737,344.54507L82.909551,345.35337L84.364495,347.45496L85.011137,350.68817L83.556193,351.33481L83.879514,352.30477L87.112725,353.11307L89.860953,353.27474L93.020842,351.58789L96.900696,355.79106L97.708998,358.05431L100.29557,362.25748L100.61889,365.49069L100.61889,374.867L101.10387,376.64526L111.12682,378.10021L130.84939,380.84843L144.69443,382.19813ZM56.559218,338.48145L57.852506,340.01723L57.690846,341.31052L54.457625,341.22969L53.891811,340.01723L53.245167,338.56228L56.559218,338.48145ZM58.49915,338.48145L59.711608,337.83481L63.268151,339.9364L66.339711,341.14885L65.450575,341.79551L60.924066,341.55301L59.307456,339.9364L58.49915,338.48145ZM79.191764,358.28493L80.970029,360.62901L81.778342,361.59898L83.314121,362.16479L83.879928,360.70984L82.909965,358.93157L80.242562,356.91081L79.191764,357.07247L79.191764,358.28493ZM77.736809,366.93379L79.515085,370.08618L80.727543,372.02612L79.272589,372.2686L77.979305,371.05615C77.979305,371.05615,77.251828,369.6012,77.251828,369.19704C77.251828,368.7929,77.251828,367.01462,77.251828,367.01462L77.736809,366.93379Z" name="California"></path>
</svg>
```

**Attempts -**
I have tried adding a ng-click event, but it doesn't seem to bind properly.

I have also looked for a way to use pushState() to trigger the event, but I have not had any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register the click event like this to the path:

```
   <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            Hello, {{name}}!
      <svg width=500 height=500>
      <path class="state" ng-click="hello()"  ...
```

In your controller define the `hello` function like this

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Cyril';
  $scope.hello = function() { //called from path click
    console.log("hello world path clicked")
  }
}
```

working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/06fueLL4/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think ng-click will work for D3 because it isn't created within an Angular context.  The items are created usually by direct DOM manipulation rather then through the Angular context.  Your D3 elements are probably created using D3 native.  So you in your chart init code you will need to add something like this:

```
d3.select("svg path.state").on("click", function() {
  // Do some stuff.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use d3's `.on("click", function)` event handler, but you need to wrap the Angular code within the function in a `$timeout` in order to trigger an Angular $digest cycle.

For example:

```
var node = mySvg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  // ...
  .on("click", function(){
    $timeout(myService.toggle);
  });
```

Here is an [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/z1hfsn40/) with an on click handler on the node